# Principle Component Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I am studying principle component analysis, and I have just learnt that before applying PCA to the data samples, we have to apply two preprocessing steps which are `mean normalization` and `feature scaling`. However, I have no idea about what mean normalization is and how it can be implemented.

At first I searched it; however, I could not find a instructive explanation. Is there anyone who can explain what is mean normalization and how it can be implemented ?

Comment: Presumably it means centering the mean around 0 or going further and doing standardization (z-values).  However, I don't know what either has to do with PCA.

Comment: If your distribution is gaussian, you can apply normalization to every data point X via ((X - mu)/sigma). I.e. subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation. Other distributions have other methods of normalization.

Comment: You could see how to do mean normalization and feature scaling [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling). However, what is more interesting is the reason behind doing it. You can read about it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69157/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-data-before-principal-component-analysis-pca).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there is a dataset with 'd' features(Columns) and 'n' Observations(Rows). For simplicity sake lets consider d=2 and n=100. Which means now you dataset has 2 features and 100 observations.
In other words, now your dataset is a 2-dimensional array with 100 rows and 2 columns - (100x2).
Initially, when you visualize it, you can see that the points are scattered in a 2 dimension.

When you standardize the dataset, and when you visualize it you can actually see that all the points have shifted towards the origin. In other words, all the observation points have a mean of value 0 and standard deviation of value 1. This process is called Standardization.

[image: Sample Data Visualization]

How do you Standardize..?
Its pretty simple. The Formula is straight forward.

```
z = (X - u) / s

Where, 

X - an observation in the feature column
u - mean of the feature column
s - standard deviation of the feature column
```

Note: You have to apply standardization with respect to all feature in the dataset

Reference:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/normalize-standardize-machine-learning-data-weka/

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html